# Unable to install cfdisk

Tags: command-line, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian, apt-get

[Following this guide](https://raymii.org/s/articles/Build_a_35_dollar_Time_Capsule_-_Raspberry_Pi_Time_Machine.html) but unable to install cfdisk.

`sudo apt-get install cfdisk`

returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cfdisk
```

RPi Model B, running Raspbian

Answer (score 5):

This is because the `cfdisk` utility is not shipped in a `cfdisk` package but in the `util-linux` package.

```
aptitude install util-linux
```

**UPDATE** With Debian 10 ("Buster") and Ubuntu 18.04 ("Bionic Beaver"), the `cfdisk` utility has been moved to a separate `fdisk` package, so currently the correct way is to install this (smaller) package:

```
apt-get install fdisk
```

Comment: Ich habe util-linux in debian 7.8 installiert. Es ist aber kein cfdisk dabei.

Comment: @Michael please use English for any questions/answers/comments, so non-German speakers can read them as well (would you have liked it if I had answered the question in Croatian?)

Comment: @Michael: util-linux *does* include `cfdisk`, confirm the [package contents](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/amd64/util-linux/filelist). You have to be `root` to run it though

Comment: @Michael: if the answer has helped you, you should *upvote* it.

Comment: Guys, here is this nice tool, called `apt-file`. In this case one can do next: `apt-file search cfdisk`, which gives the answer: `util-linux: /sbin/cfdisk`.

Comment: @SamProtsenko i know a lot of nice tools :-) i'm not really sure how your comment improves anything here - i think it was already established that `util-linux` does include `cfdisk`. for the record: i used `dpkg -S /sbin/cfdisk` to get the package

Comment: @umläute, it improves things in a way that op can use this tool next time to figure out correct package name by himself instead of asking a question on SO :)